# OutputFormat NotSupported in Birt Report Engine API

Tags: birt

I want to render a previously designed BIRT report  to HTML in Eclipse Indigo. I am using BIRT 4.2.1. When I do it in a normal Java application it runs fine. However, when I want to do the same from a RCP application it does not.

This is my code:

```
    IRunAndRenderTask task=null;
    IReportEngine engine=null;
    EngineConfig config = null;
    IReportRunnable design = null;

    try{

        config = new EngineConfig( );

        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.
        createFactoryObject( IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );

        engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );
        //use this if the report is in the bundle
        Bundle bundle = org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle("com.accenture.workforceplanning.ui");      
        URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/reports/scenarioAnalysis.rptdesign"), null);
        String rpt = FileLocator.toFileURL(url).getPath();

    //Open the report design
    design = engine.openReportDesign(rpt); 
    task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);


    HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();      
    options.setImageDirectory("./");
    URL url1 = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/reports"), null);
    String rpt1 = FileLocator.toFileURL(url1).getPath();
    options.setOutputFileName(rpt1 +"/scenarioAnalysis.html");
    options.setOutputFormat("html");

    task.setRenderOption(options);
    task.run();
    task.close();
    engine.destroy();
    }catch( Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When the program reaches the task.run() I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.UnsupportedFormatException: The output format html is not supported.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.setupRenderOption(EngineTask.java:2047)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.accenture.workforceplanning.ui.composites.OutputComposite.reportToHtml(OutputComposite.java:470)
    at com.accenture.workforceplanning.ui.composites.OutputComposite.createReportScenarioAnalysis(OutputComposite.java:410)
    at com.accenture.workforceplanning.ui.composites.OutputComposite.access$6(OutputComposite.java:308)
    at com.accenture.workforceplanning.ui.composites.OutputComposite$4.widgetSelected(OutputComposite.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.accenture.workforceplanning.application.Application.start(Application.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

It happens the same for any type of outputformat that I want to render.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Yulexi

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve issue. Just in case somebody encounters the same problem this is what I did:
*I added manually all the BIRT plug-ins to the dependencies of the product of my RCP application*(For some reason, the required plug-ins were not added). Still I don't know what was the missing plug-in. But the application  works fine now.